# Why is the total number of possible substrings of a string n^2?

Tags: algorithm, counting

I read that the total number of substrings that can be formed from a given string is n^2 but I don't understand how to count this.

By substrings, I mean, given a string CAT, the substrings would be:

```
C
CA
CAT
A
AT
T
```

Comment: Where did you read that? What's the context?

Comment: For "CAT", `n` is 3. 3 * 3 = 9. But there are only 6 substrings. So you are asking for proof of a falsehood. It's n(n -1). Maybe you meant O(n^2)?

Comment: Don't you mean it's O(n^2)?

Comment: @erickon: There's also the empty string, and possibly `CT` in the case OP meant power sets (and in this case, there are `2^n` subsets, not `n^2`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The total number of (nonempty) substrings is `n + C(n,2)`. The leading `n` counts the number of substrings of length 1 and `C(n,2)` counts the number of substrings of length > 1 and is equal to the number of ways to choose 2 indices from the set of `n`. The standard formula for binomial coefficients yields `C(n,2) = n*(n-1)/2`. Combining these two terms and simplifying gives that the total number is `(n^2 + n)/2`. @rici in the comments notes that this is the same as `C(n+1,2)` which makes sense if you e.g. think in terms of Python string slicing where substrings of `s` can always be written in the form `s[i:j]` where `0 <= i < j <= n` (with `j` being 1 more than the final index). For `n = 3` this works out to `(9 + 3)/2 = 6`.

In the sense of complexity theory the number of substrings *is* `O(n^2)`, which might be what you read somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, what about n = 2? The number of substrings according to n*(n-1)/2 would be 1, but clearly there are 3 possibilities, e.g. AB -> AB, A, B - unless I'm misunderstanding your response?

Comment: No - it is `n + n(n-1)/2`. The `n*(n-1)/2` part is the `C(n,2)` term.

Comment: That would be `C(n+1,2)`, which makes sense since there are `n+1` *positions* in a string with `n` characters

Comment: @rici -- Good observation. Note that `n + C(n,2)` comes from `C(n,1) + C(n,2)` and `C(n+1,2) = C(n,1) + C(n,2)` is a special case of the recursive formula for binomial coefficients that underlies Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Sure, the mathematical equivalence is clear. The focus on positions rather than indices explains the use of the binomial coefficient, though, don't you think? Your answer really doesn't explain why you need to add `n`.

Comment: @rici -- I'll edit it to make it clearer -- I thought of it as counting substrings of length 1 (specified by a single index) + substrings of length > 1 (specified by a pair of distinct indices), though your way of thinking about it is also natural.

Answer (score 0):

You have a starting point and and end point - if each could point to anywhere along the word, each would have n possible values, and therefor an overall of n^2, so that's an upper limit.

However, we need a constraint saying that the substring cannot end before it started, so `end - start >=0`. This cuts the possible count in about half, but on asymptotic terms it's still O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Substring calculation is logically

```
selecting 2 blank spaces atleast one letter apart.

a| b c | d = substring bc
| a b c |d = substring abc.

Now how many ways can you chose these 2 blankspace. For n letter word there are n+1.

Then first select one = n+1 ways
Select another (not the same)= n
So total n(n+1). But you have calculated everything twice. So n*(n+1)/2.


Programmatically, without applying any special algorithms(like Z algo etc) you can use a map to calculate no of distinct substrings.(O(n^3)).
```

You can use suffix tree to get O(n^2) substring calculaton.

Answer (score 0):

To get a substring of a given string `s`, you just need to select two different points in the string. Let  `s` contain `n` characters,

`|s[0]|s[1]|...|s[n-1]|`

You want to choose two `vertical bars` to get a substring. How many `vertical bars` do you have? Exactly `n+1`. So the number of sustrings is `C(n+1,2) = n(n+1)/2`, which is to choose `2` items from `n+1`. Of course, it could be denoted as `O(n^2)`.